# Seaborn stripplot based on columns

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
Group   Exp1          Exp2        Exp3         Exp4     Exp5    Control
0   1   0.005556    -0.101111   0.052632    -0.055556   0.033333    y
1   2   -0.115684   0.076667    -0.349497   0.555556    0.555556    n
2   3   0.184444    0.251397    0.022222    -0.444444   0.611650    n
3   4   0.075556    0.237778    0.368750    0.098901    -0.111111   n
4   5   -0.186916   -0.355556   0.172414    0.087120    0.034737    y
5   6   0.250000    0.152542    -0.395349   0.111111    0.000000    n
6   7   -0.025014   0.030000    0.594444    0.055556    0.311111    n
7   8   -0.062500   0.123333    0.317778    0.144444    0.288889    n
8   9   0.001111    0.141111    0.181111    0.011111    0.435897    n
9   10  -0.124444   -0.074241   0.074444    -0.111111   0.133333    y
```

Now the typical seaborn stripplot uses the rows to plot different categories.
I would like to, however, have the different categories be the columns (the different experiments)
and plot the 10 values for each group and each experiment vertically above the experiments marker on the x-axis.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the column you don't want to plot and pass the rest to `data`:

```
sns.stripplot(data=df.drop("Group", axis=1))
```

[image]

It's good to learn how to do the full transformation to long-form data that @JohanC demonstrates, but also good to know how to take advantage of the [wide-form data](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html) support when it fits with what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you - that has been an incredibly simple and useful solution! I have an additional question: I have added the column "control" and tried to use "hue" for two different colors in the entire plot only depending on control yes/no - but this does not seem to work: sns.stripplot(data=df.drop("Group", axis=1), hue="Control") - why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn usually [works easiest with "long form" data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html), so with one column indicating the experiment and another the corresponding values. Seaborn also accepts some kinds of "wide" data for sufficiently simple structured dataframes. In this case, converting the "Group" column to an index would do the job.

So, it looks like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({f'Exp{i}': np.random.randn(10) for i in range(1, 6)})
df['Group'] = range(1, 11)
ax = sns.stripplot(data=df.set_index('Group'))
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

The wide form doesn't support `hue` in this case (`sns.stripplot(data=df.drop(columns=['Group', 'Control']), hue=df['Control'])`) gives an error telling that `hue` is not supported when `x` and `y` are not explicitly set.

But the "long form" can be used.
Pandas [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) converts a dataframe to the desired long form:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''   Group   Exp1          Exp2        Exp3         Exp4     Exp5    Control
0   1   0.005556    -0.101111   0.052632    -0.055556   0.033333    y
1   2   -0.115684   0.076667    -0.349497   0.555556    0.555556    n
2   3   0.184444    0.251397    0.022222    -0.444444   0.611650    n
3   4   0.075556    0.237778    0.368750    0.098901    -0.111111   n
4   5   -0.186916   -0.355556   0.172414    0.087120    0.034737    y
5   6   0.250000    0.152542    -0.395349   0.111111    0.000000    n
6   7   -0.025014   0.030000    0.594444    0.055556    0.311111    n
7   8   -0.062500   0.123333    0.317778    0.144444    0.288889    n
8   9   0.001111    0.141111    0.181111    0.011111    0.435897    n
9   10  -0.124444   -0.074241   0.074444    -0.111111   0.133333    y'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
###df.set_index('Group', inplace=True)
##ax = sns.stripplot(data=df.drop(columns=['Control']), hue=df['Control'])

long_df = df.melt(id_vars=['Group', 'Control'], var_name='Experiment', value_name='Value')
ax = sns.stripplot(data=long_df, x='Experiment', y='Value', hue='Control')
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: long form]

The long form of the dataframe looks like:

```py
   Group Control Experiment     Value
0      1       y       Exp1  0.005556
1      2       n       Exp1 -0.115684
2      3       n       Exp1  0.184444
3      4       n       Exp1  0.075556
4      5       y       Exp1 -0.186916
...
```

Comment: Thank you - did you change the values? Because Exp5 never has anything below -1

Comment: Yes, the function creates random values to quickly create an independent test.

Comment: Does this answer your second question?